# how to get db unique ids for html form and use it in css and jquery for making dyanmic forms for each form data for django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I made an edit button which for edit existing data. When pressing the button it will show the form and if there are multiple data then there will be multiple edit buttons which leads to showing multiple forms. 
The problem is, I cannot get make this. All my edit buttons and forms are visible. All I need is an edit button that shows the form and it will be dynamic as the DB object id's. I'm using Django as a backend for the edit form to save the edited data.
code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".formButton").click(function() {
    var togle= $('this').attr("id")
    print(togle)

    $(togle).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
h1,h2{
  font-style: italic;
  color: green;
  background-color: inherit;
}
/* .djangoaccessed{
  border: 2px solid black;
} */
table, th, td{
  border: .5px solid black;
}


.hello{

  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is Django TODO APP.</h1>

      {% comment %} <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">

          <form method="get" action="/search1/">
      <p><label for="id_q">Search:</label>

      <select name="topic">
        {% for todo in all_todo %}
          <option value="{{ todo.id }}">{{ todo.topic }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
      </form>

  </div>

</div> {% endcomment %}


  {% comment %} <div class="container">

    <select name="topic">
   {% for todo in all_todo %}
   <option value="{{todo.id}}">{{ todo.topic }}</option>
   {% endfor %}
 </select>
 <br><br>
  </div> {% endcomment %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">



    {% if all_todo %}
    <table >
      <thead>

        <th>Topic</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Date-time</th>

      </thead>
      {% for todo in all_todo %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ todo.topic }}</td>
      <td>{{ todo.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ todo.content }}</td>
      <td>{{ todo.datetime }}</td>
      <td>
        <form action="/deltodo/{{todo.id}}/"  method="post" style="display: inline;">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="submit"  value="Delete">
        </form>
      </td>
      <td><button type="button" class="formButton" id="{{todo.id}}">Edit</button> {% comment %} update data {% endcomment %}
      <div class="container">
                <form action="/updatetodo/{{todo.id}}/"  method="post" id="hello-{{todo.id}}" class='formid' >
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <label for="topics">Add Activity:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="topic" placeholder="update your todo type" value={{ todo.topic }}>
                  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="update your todo name" value={{ todo.name }}>
                  <input type="text" name="content" placeholder="update your todo description" value={{ todo.content }}>
                  <input type="datetime-local" name="datetime" value="{{ todo.datetime }}">
                  <input type="submit"  value="Save">

                </form>
                </div>
              </td>
    </tr>

      {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% else %}
    <p>No data found!</p>
    {% endif %}
    {% comment %} </div>
    </div>







          {% comment %} save data {% endcomment %}
          <div class="container">

                    <form action="/addtodo/"  method="post" >
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <label for="topics">Add Activity:</label>
                      <input type="text" name="topic" placeholder="Input your todo type">
                      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Input your todo name">
                      <input type="text" name="content" placeholder="Input your todo description">
                      <input type="datetime-local" name="datetime" >
                      <input type="submit"  value="Save">

                    </form>
                    </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        <script src="{% static "js/form.js" %}">  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would recommend reading up on Django's Formsets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/ and since you're already using jquery this package would help you too https://pypi.org/project/django-formset-bootstrap/

Comment: I do not fully understand what your problem is. Are you struggling with javascript to show / hide a form or are struggling with Django forms and formsets?

Comment: I am struggling with javascript show/hide. I add an edit button and after pressing edit it will show a form. However, it is not working.